# how to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 from my DVD to my Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, visual-studio

I'm migrating a Visual Basic windows app from my home Windows 2008 physical server up to my new Azure VM.

I have a purchased Visual Studio 2010 DVD.
Using my Visual Basic 2010, I created a publish package folder and copied it up to the VM.

How do I install my Visual Studio 2010 DVD up to the VM, so that I can run the package on the VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the DVD contents to the VM and run the installer. Or download an ISO image from MSDN directly on the VM.

Comment: And first I edited the .rdp file and enabled mounting my local DVD driver.